# URL key for specified store already exists for category and product also

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

I imported my category and product from `csv` file.These are  working great , but trying to edit product or category then getting error URL key for specified store already exists. For solution I have cleared `url_rewrite` table . But this issue not resolve. Please help